# AppManifest.xml not getting updated by SL build

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting an SL project in VS2010, and I'm finding that the AppManifest.xml file isn't being updated by the build. This causes the xap to fail to load in the browser, throwing an `InitializationException`. Doesn't VS maintain this file for you?

I noted that the `Build Action` listed for the AppManifest.xml file is currently "None", but I'm not sure what I should change that to, if anything.

Comment: What's leading you to think that the problem lies with the AppManifest.xml file?  On my Silverlight apps, this file is basically empty (nothing in Deployment.Parts), the build doesn't touch it, and the Build Action is set to None -- and yet the apps are running and loading correctly.  You may be misinterpreting how this file is used.  I suspect there's a different problem behind your InitializationException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I didn't have any `Application` class in my project, nor the required `App.xaml`. (I had somehow deleted these files when attempting to customize the solution.) This caused the xap to fail to load, and the error message led me to believe that the root cause was the AppManifest.xml, which generates the AppManifest.xaml file.

This was a mistake. Fixing the `Application` class and the App.xaml solved the problem.